# How can one globally define a variable in a visual studio 2010 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

Is there any way one can define for a solution a global variable accessable by any project file or project property sheet included in the solution?

One variable is enough if that can define a path for a property sheet that every project can include.

This is desirably for a solution.
An environment variable would be ok though less desirable.

**** (visual studion 2010)

Poking at it again, I can't see how to set a user defined $(xxx) vartiable in a project - yes you can in a property sheet, but In a project I have reference to the $(ProjectDir) -

The problem is I want to define a $(tree of projects root) that any project that references a specific poject can access and the root will be relative to that project.

An alternative would be if a property sheet can have access to its own path and define the project collection root (of a tree of related projects with common resources) relative to that.

It seems every one building a big system with VS has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your use case but it doesn't sound like the best idea.  This will tie all of your projects together very tightly, which violates good OO design.  Microsoft hasn't included any solution-level properties for this reason.  However, if you really want to do something like this, you have two ways (at least) to go about it.

The first way, and the way I would recommend against, would be to store the variable in one of your projects and make it public.  Then all of your projects could access it as long as they include the project as a reference.

The second way, and the way that will retain some OO principles, would be to create a config file that all projects looked at for the variable.  This could be an XML file, a CSV file, or even a simple text file.  If you wanted to get more complicated, you could point to a database location since this is one of the roles of a database.

Comment: Right first way is bad projects should not have to know about each other. this is for VisualStudio - not for MSBuild.

Comment: oops the 5 minue rule :) Right first way is bad projects should not have to know about each other. this is for VisualStudio - not for MSBuild.  I figure one can have a property sheet named the same as the solution? and all projects could import $(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName).vsprops  ??  I basicly want it so a solution can specify a path to the root of a set of related projects and config overides that affect the build oe fll the projects in a common manner, library sets etc.  If the above works then the solution can effectively define which global property sheet to include.